# Wrap multiple divs with class within a single wrapper div?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop

I have a wordpress loop that outputs my posts inside a div. Those div's have these classes `.col1,.col2,.col3`. The output looks like this:

[image]

Now I need to wrap those divs within a ***single wrapper*** div.

For example all `.col1` should be wrapped within a single wrapper div with class `.left`, `.col2` should be wrapped with a single div with class `.middle` and `.coll3` should be wrapped with with div class '`.right`'.

*I do not know how many divs will be within my page.*

So the final output should look like this:

[image]

My loop looks like this:

```
<?php       
        $col = 1; // Let's create first column. 

         if ( have_posts() ) : ?><?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class( 'col' . $col ); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <?php if ( 1 === $col ) {// If column 1 create first row.
                echo '<div class="row">';
            } 
            ?>
            <?php if ( 2 === $col ) {// If column 2 create second row.
                echo '<div class="row2">';
            } 
            ?>
            <?php if ( 3 === $col ) {// If column 3 create third row.
                echo '<div class="row3">';
            } 
            ?>

            <!--Get the Three Columns Content -->
            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'three-columns' ); ?>

            <?php /* Close Three Column Layout Div's */
            if ( 1 === $col ) {
                $col = 2;
                echo '</div>';
            } else if ( 2 === $col ) {
                $col = 3;
                echo '</div>';
            } else if ( 3 === $col ) {
                $col = 1;
                echo '</div>';
            }
            endwhile; ?>



            <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

            <?php endif;?>
```

Can this be done with PHP only without `js`? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reorganize how you are outputting your posts. Instead of looping through them row-wise, you need to change it to column-wise, so you can create your outer `<div>` elements correctly.

Imagine you have 10 posts. Instead of looping through them in order, from 1 to 10, you need to group them into 3 chunks (for three columns), then iterate over each column.

```
Old: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
New: (1, 4, 7, 10) (2, 5, 8) (3, 6, 9)
```

Here is a simple example on how you do just that, along with forming your `<div>` elements with the correct classes:

```
$posts = range(1, 10); // Collect all of your posts into an array, as an example I'm just using numbers.

$posts_reordered = ['left' => [], 'middle' => [], 'right' => []];

foreach(array_chunk($posts, 3) as $chunk) {
    $posts_reordered['left'][] = $chunk[0];     
    if(isset($chunk[1])) {
        $posts_reordered['middle'][] = $chunk[1];
    }
    if(isset($chunk[2])) {
        $posts_reordered['right'][] = $chunk[2];
    }
}
```

Now your posts are reorganized by columns instead of by rows, so you can print your desired HTML:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($posts_reordered as $key => $column_posts) {
    $outer_div_class = ".$key"; // .left

    echo "<div class='$outer_div_class'>\n";

    foreach($column_posts as $post) {
        $inner_div_class = ".col$i";
        echo "\t<div class='$inner_div_class'>$post</div>\n\n";
    }

    echo "</div>\n";
    $i++;
}
```

This [will output](https://3v4l.org/kUX8Z):

```
<div class='.left'>
    <div class='.col1'>1</div>

    <div class='.col1'>4</div>

    <div class='.col1'>7</div>

    <div class='.col1'>10</div>

</div>
<div class='.middle'>
    <div class='.col2'>2</div>

    <div class='.col2'>5</div>

    <div class='.col2'>8</div>

</div>
<div class='.right'>
    <div class='.col3'>3</div>

    <div class='.col3'>6</div>

    <div class='.col3'>9</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Break your data up into 3 columns first the build the columns individually then render in sequence.

```
function buildCols( $posts ){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($posts); $i += 3) {
        $threeColArray[] = array_slice($posts, $i, 3);
    }
    return $threeColArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, you can end the column and start a new column if the post counter is divisible by 3:

```
<?php             
$post_counter = 1;
$col_counter = 1;
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="col--<?php echo $col_counter; ?>">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php if ($post_counter % 3 == 0) : ?>
        <?php $col_counter++; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col--<?php echo $col_counter; ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>

        <!--Get the Three Columns Content -->
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'three-columns' ); ?>


        <?php $post_counter++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First note that since much your file is php there is no need to keep opening and closing the php tags for every line.

Simply place `<?` at the top of your file. As you output your html with `echo` you don't even need to close the tag. You would then replace your `:` with `{` and your `endif` with `}`. It will make your code much cleaner.

That said you should probably just create a local variable to store the divs then print the content in a seperate loop.

Here is the rough idea:

```
<?php
  // Set up a local variable.
  $columns= array();

  // Collect the data.
  while (have_posts)
  {
    the_post();
    $columns[$col] .= '<div class=col-' . $col . '>' . get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'three-columns' ) . '</div>';
  }

  // Output the data.
  foreach($columns as $col => $data)
  {
    echo '<div class="column-' . $col . '-wrapper">' . $data . '</div>';
  }
```

Comment: Hmm tried it  but it is not working... I am guessing `while (have_posts)` should be `while (have_posts())` and to be honest i do not know how to store div's classes into `$columns= array();` can you provide an example? Yeah i suck with PHP:(

Comment: Im not very familiar with Wordpress so I cant really help with that part. This is fairly generic code so you should be able to extract what you need. Just experiment until it gets there. Thats how you learn.